# Drag Re-sizable 2 column layout

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I just tried to create a Drag re-sizable layout with jQuery ui

http://jsfiddle.net/3zLRJ/

But my actual aim was something like this

[image]

Is it possible to make it with jQuery Ui method ?, or any other plugins available

Comment: +1 for neatly explain the question.

Comment: in your image you mean resizable by dragable?right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin doesn't support it by default, so I made a start for you to achieve the goal. I just hard coded the div's into the function for the `resize event`, it's up to you to make it dynamic ;).

```
var total_width = 500;

$("#div1").resizable({
    grid: [1, 10000]
}).bind( "resize", resize_other);


function resize_other(event, ui) {
    var width = $("#div1").width();

    if(width > total_width) {
        width = total_width;

        $('#div1').css('width', width);
    }

    $('#div2').css('width', (total_width - width));
}​
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3zLRJ/4/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Set the `handles` property of the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/3zLRJ/5/

You'll need to add code to adjust both divs when one is being resized, though, through the `resize` event.

Another option is to create a third div between the two, make it a `draggable`, and constrain its motion to only go side to side. Then, adjust the divs around it on the `drag` event.